# Laravel 5 Validation fails (field not set)

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, laravel-5.1

Hi im currently coding a gallery in laravel 5 where you can upload images and videos in separted categorys and i got a pretty strange problem with the valdidation method.

The image upload itself works fine and does exactly what it should.
But if i try to upload videos (mp4,webm) my Validation always fails with the error, that the file field is required. But if i try the same with a wrong mime type file all works like intended and i the validation method says its the wrong mime type.

The view looks the following:

```
@extends('templates.base')
@section('content')
@parent
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/gallery/upload/' .$gallery->id, 'files' => true]) !!}
<div>
    {!! $error !!}
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Title:
        </td>
        <td>
            {!! Form::text('title',old('title'),['class' => 'form_text', 'min' => '3', 'max' => '255']) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Description:
        </td>
        <td>
            {!! Form::textarea('description') !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            File:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
            {!! Form::file('file') !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            External:
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="external">
                <option value="0" default>No</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{!! Form::submit(trans('strings.create'),['class' => 'form_submit news']) !!}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

The controller looks something like this:

```
if (config('gallery.allowUploads')) {
        if (config('gallery.allowUserUploads')) {
            $gallery = Gallery::find($request->route('id'));

            if (is_null($request->route('id')) || count($gallery) <= 0) {
                return redirect()->back();
            }

            if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
                if ($gallery->type == 'i') {
                    $Validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                        'title'       => 'required|min:3|max:255',
                        'description' => 'max:10000',
                        'file'        => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,gif',
                        'external'    => 'required|in:0,1',
                    ]);
                } elseif ($gallery->type == 'v') {
                    $Validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                        'title'       => 'required|min:3|max:255',
                        'description' => 'max:10000',
                        'file'        => 'required|mimes:mp4,webm',
                        'external'    => 'required|in:0,1',
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $Validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                        'title'       => 'required|min:3|max:255',
                        'description' => 'max:10000',
                        'file'        => 'required|mimes:zip,rar,7z',
                        'external'    => 'required|in:0,1',
                    ]);
                }
                $error = "";

                if ($Validator->fails()) {
                    foreach ($Validator->messages()->All() as $m) {
                        $error .= $m . "</br>";
                    }
                    return view('gallery/items/create', ['gallery' => $gallery, 'error' => $error);
                }
```

When im uploading a webm

```
dd($request->file('file'),$gallery->type);
```

returns

```
UploadedFile {#29 ▼
   -test: false
   -originalName: "big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"
   -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
   -size: 0
   -error: 1
   }
   "v"
```

But the Validation Method still says it fails because the file field is required.

I just feel like i'm overlooking something. Thanks for your help.

edit:

i just found that when im uploading an image file i get

```
UploadedFile {#29 ▼
   -test: false
   -originalName: "a8b5KQQ_460s_v1.jpg"
   -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
   -size: 53991
   -error: 0
}
"v"
```

that error is 0 and on the webm file its 1 but i'm not sure what it means.

Comment: I actually found out that this has to do something with the file i tried to upload. I got my hands on a few other sample files where there was no problem at when i tried to upload them. The question is why has the first webm a "application/octet-stream" mime type because it seems like its a normal webm. And the second one is why don't i get a fail because of the wrong mime instead of the file not set exeption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output it looks like the file is empty and for some reason an mime type cannot be found. If you delve into
[symfony\Httpfoundation\File\UploadedFile](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/File/UploadedFile.php) 
you will see the constructor has the following assignment:

`$this->mimeType = $mimeType ?: 'application/octet-stream';`

Which seems to be why you are getting `application/octet-stream` as your Mime Type.

Because Laravels `request->file('file');` returns an instance of `symfony\Httpfoundation\File\UploadedFile` - which performs some checks on the file when the object is constructed - I would guess that whatever error is detected causes Laravel to assume that no file has been uploaded and therefore doesn't perform the validation.

Either way, the file doesn't make it on to your server, which is good. Incidentally, you should be able to call `$request->file('file')->getErrorMessage()`; which should tell you what it thinks the problem was.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was exactly what I wanted to know. The error was very simple. `"The file "big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB)."` I'm allready on a function to check the max file size set in the ini just hadn't implemented it yet.

Comment: You could just call the static `UploadedFile::getMaxFilesize()` method for that, which might save you same time.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given you the namespace. UploadFile is part of symfony, but as Laravel uses this class for file uploads you might as well use it if it makes your life easier. you can find the documentation for this particular class at: [http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html)